# I want to understand how this expansion of a matrix to this inverse of partitioned matrix form is done.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics, education, block-matrices

I see people making use of this technique to represent 4 energy bands problems to 2 bands problems in condensed matter physics (I'm looking at bilayer graphene particularly).

[original matrix in its partitioned form_eq.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLpQ7.png)

[image: original matrix in its partitioned form_eq.1]

[matrix expanded_eq.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/denDs.png)

[image: matrix expanded_eq.2]

a) I wish to understand how we go from this original matrix to the expanded form of the matrix.

b) And also, how this second equation makes sense.

c) And how representing 4 band hamiltonian matrix in an effective 2 band hamiltonian matrix make sense.

Comment: $H_{eff}$ is a [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement)

Comment: What is the relationship between $\mathcal H_{\text{eff}}$ and $\mathcal H$?